# Unable to use Infinispan embedded cachemanager on JBoss EAP 7.2

Tags: infinispan, jboss-eap-7, java-ee-8

I need to use cache system on my web application under JBoss EAP 7.2

My purpose is to configure cache at application level, therefore no server configuration should be required.

The cache provider is *Infinispan*

This is my pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan-hibernate-cache-v53</artifactId>
            <version>${version.infinispan}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
            <version>${version.infinispan}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

${version.infinispan} is 9.3.3.Final, the version shipped by JBoss EAP 7.2 (see also https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673)

When I try to start the AS, i have got this error:

```
[...] a class it references was not found: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManager
```

Guess I have to configure it on manifest or something else, 
however I haven't found how.

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT

On RedHat page is reported the following sentence:

```
Infinispan is delivered as a private module in EAP to provide the caching capabilities of EAP. Infinispan is not supported for direct use by application
```

Does it mean that I can't use infinispan cache directly ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add caching to EAP for your own data, you should use JBoss Datagrid (downstream) or Infinispan (upstream) modules, so that you have full control over the version and capabilities of the caching layer. See [this quickstart](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-jdg-quickstarts/tree/jdg-7.3.x/eap-cluster-app) to do just that.

The version that ships with EAP is fixed and does not contain all the Infinispan modules, so we recommend against directly using this.